# bwu_datagrid - how to disable call of Editor for some cells in column?

Tags: dart, bwu-datagrid

I use `bwu_datagrid` and some columns in my datagrid have cells that I don't want to be edited. Is there an existing way for this in `bwu_datagrid`? Returning null in Editor.newInstance(EditorArgs) brings to exception in _currentEditor.loadValue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just **not** assigning an editor in the column definition (`Column(id: 'someid', name: 'Title', ...)`) should have that effect.

To disable just specific cells listen to `onBwuBeforeEditCell`

```dart
grid.onBwuBeforeEditCell.listen((BeforeEditCell e) {
  if (!isCellEditable(e.cell.row, e.cell.cell, e.item)) {
    e.retVal = false;
  }
});
```

Comment: :) So I disable Editor for entire column but I want to do it for some cells in the column only.